# Which method is called when back button clicked in navigation controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, controller, navigation, back-button

I want to save DB when the back button clicked in navigation controller.

so I would insert code in method.

What method is called when back button clicked in navigation controller?

Comment: Use a flag variable. If DB is not-updated then updated-DB in viewWillDisappear method. This should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do what you asked, look at the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol, namely the method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

when the viewController argument is no longer your view controller then you should save.

However, doing so on `viewWillDisappear:` might be a better (and much simpler) idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not appropriate use, but that worked for me. Don't forget to set UINavaigationController delegate.

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                  toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    NSLog(@"from VC class %@", [fromVC class]);
    if ([fromVC isKindOfClass:[ControllerYouJustPopped class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Returning from popped controller");

    }

    return nil;
}
```