# How to check whether the ViewController is popped or pushed without using the BOOL variable?

Tags: ios

How to check whether the ViewController is popped or pushed without using the BOOL variable ? Is there any inbuilt method that tells the whether it si popped or pushed ??

Comment: Could you try explaining a little more the issue? What are you trying to do exactly? Are you talking about UIVIewControllers being push and popped inside an UINavigationController?

Comment: I want to set animation for the navigation controller and for that i need to check whether the view is popped or pushed when it is displayed ... so that based on that i can add different kind of animation....

Comment: @ParvezBelim whats wrong with my answer and why down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (self.navigationController != nil) {
    // You can POP
}
```

or get All views.

```
NSArray* views = [myNavigationController viewControllers];
 [views objectAtIndex:0] //will be the Root
```

And Can check current is Root or not like

`if(self == [views objectAtIndex:0])`
//Yes it is Root

Comment: DownVoter thanks but please write comment ?

Comment: please comment what's wrong in my answer. why downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

for the following, please note: you need to have the same instance of the `toCheckController` to get the correct result

```
NSArray* views = [myNavigationController viewControllers];

[views containsObject: toCheckController];//will return you yes/no
```

This will tell you if it is already pushed or not. If this returns NO, you cannot tell whether the view was popped or never pushed.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIViewController` has a property called `isMovingToParentViewController`. You can call this in your `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` methods. If the vc is pushed it's `true`, if it's popped it's `false`.

Here is a similar answer:
[iOS how to detect programmatically when top view controller is popped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380905/ios-how-to-detect-programmatically-when-top-view-controller-is-popped)

Edit: (Only available in iOS 5 and up)

Comment: yes it works in few cases but not in all cases ... i tried the alternative one also that is 
- (BOOL)isBeingPresented NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
but this are also not working ... because to use this we have to place this function in view will disappear ... and i placed the animation code in view will apear method of another view control ... so after disappear is called another view's viewWillApear() is called...So not working in my case...but this is correct solution..I finally used BOOL to sort out the issue ...Thanx Tobi