# Better way to identify if a viewController was reached by popping the navigationController or using the tab-bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Attempt to clarify: I would like to be able to differentiate between the two following scenarios:

- a viewController's view becoming active as result of a pop.
- a viewController's view becoming active as result of tabBar-navigation

---

In the app I'm working on I need to know if a viewController was presented due to its navigationController being popped or not. I had a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380905/ios-how-to-detect-programmatically-when-top-view-controller-is-popped) and thought I had found the solution by simply calling:

```
BOOL wasReachedByPopping = !self.isMovingToParentViewController;
```

in my `viewWillAppear:` method

This works fine for most cases, but will unfortunately give a false positive when switching navigationControllers via a tabBarController. I've been thinking about adding a `BOOL` to my viewController called pushedNewController that will be set to YES prior to pushing.

```
self.pushedNewController = YES; // whenever I plan to push
```

This should work just fine, but I am really unhappy about having to base this on something as messy as long-lasting BOOL states. Anyone has a better approach to identify whether the viewController was reached by a pop or not?

---

Edit: I appreciate the effort below, but it seems they just offer the exact same functionality I already have. There are no methods there differentiating between being popped to or moved to through tab-bar-navigation. Seems I will have to settle on an internal BOOL to store whether the viewController requested a push or not. I set it up the following way, for anyone interested:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.disappearedDueToPush = (self != [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to recap, there seems to be no way outside storing the fact that the push was performed as a state. From the answers provided below, this state can be set by implementing the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and using the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    self.disappearedDueToPush = !(viewController == self);
}
```

If implementing the delegate seems a bit heavy handed (it did to me) you might up the following in your viewDidDisappear method instead:

```
if (self != [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject]){
    self.disappearedDueToPush = YES;
}
```

This made more sense to me as the reverse logic (and checking towards the fact) is performed in the viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods:

```
– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
– navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```

These are called when a view controller is pushed on or popped off your nav stack.

See [Apple docs](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html&ei=hjvyUsCMNKTu0gW_tYCoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEaEsRZXzkjtoTuzPj9DpINSSSMnA&sig2=4NffXCcSRR4hsylS52ZGSA&bvm=bv.60799247,d.d2k) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You want `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, specifically, the `didShowViewController:` method. Here's a usage example:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewController == self) {
        NSLog(@"%@",viewController);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but from what I can see this is called both when the viewController is popping to a viewController and when accessed through a tabbarcontroller. In other words the exact same states I achieve checking the `!self.isMovingToParentViewController;` in my viewWillAppear. I need to differentiate between being popped to, and moved through by the tab-bar...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if conditon for whether the viewcontroller is popped or not!!!

```
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewControllerObj] == NSNotFound)
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerObj animated:YES];
}
else
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllerObj animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:<Your View Controller>])
{
    NSLog(@"It is Pushed");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"It is Poped");
}
```