# conditional refreshing of view in tabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, tabbar

i have implemented a tabbarcontroller with 5 tabs each connected to a view.

the tabBarcontroller is created and default view allocation happens in another view.

everythine looks fine but i have a bug.

each view in the tab have buttons that trigger other views. these views don't have tabs so to get back to a tab view i use a back button.

when i press the back button i don't want the view ( with the tab ) to be created from scratch. so i have put the relevant code in viewdidload rather than viewwillappear. 
( this choice is because this view downloads data from server and it becomes time consuming to put the code at this point in viewwillappear )

However if i am returning from current tab to a tab that i had previously touched and viewed. I want view to be loaded from scratch because  data should be downloaded again at this point. but since i am using viewdidload rather than viewwillappear the old view is not refreshed.

how can i achieve this conditional refreshing of view depending upon whether i am coming from another tab or a from a view with back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is the `isMovingToParentViewController` method in your view controller. This will enable you to detect if your current stack has been popped from navigation controller.

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381166/361247) that explains how to use it, and links to Apple's documentation.

As you can see from that thread, you can also use `NSNotificationCenter` to do this.