# Detecting when a view controller is visible

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, uinavigationitem

## The Situation

Let's say that I have 2 view controllers inside a navigation controller. Inside the storyboard, they would look like:

NC -> VC1 -> VC2

NC: Navigation controller

VC1: View controller one

VC2: View controller 2

So VC1 is the root view controller of the navigation controller, and VC1 is connected to VC2 via a show segue.

### What must happen:

VC1 must call a function every time it opens, (e.g `necessaryFunction()`). It currently calls this function in `viewDidLoad()`. The problem is that when the user presses the back button in VC2 (the one on the navigation bar) and VC1 is now showing, `viewDidLoad()` is not called. This means that `necessaryFunction()` will not be called either.

## What I am looking for:

I am looking for a way to make sure that `necessaryFunction()` is called when returning to VC1 from VC2. I understand that this could be solved with a delegate, but that seems overly complicated for such a simple thing, surely there is another way to do this.

Maybe I could put `necessaryFunction()` into `viewWillAppear()`, but I don't think this would work.

By the way: I am coding in Swift.

**EDIT:** I have found this post: [iOS how to detect programmatically when top view controller is popped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380905/ios-how-to-detect-programmatically-when-top-view-controller-is-popped?rq=1), but it is for objective-C, not swift.

Comment: "but I don't think this would work." You don't? What happened when you _tried_ it?

Comment: When I tried it, nothing changed from when `necessaryFunction()` was called inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: But `viewWillAppear` _is_ called when you pop back to VC1, so why doesn't that solve the problem?  If it doesn't, you must be describing the problem incorrectly.

Comment: You are expressing two major misunderstandings. (1) *View controllers* are UIViewControllers, and thus, are **not** visible! (UIViews, on the other hand, are.) It sounds like you haven't grasped some basics of MVC. (2) The next - and larger - misunderstanding I'm seeing is about views, their controllers, and life cycles each have. Search on some of those terms - you should know that *viewWillAppear()* will be called while *viewDidLoad()* likely won't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS how to detect programmatically when top view controller is popped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380905/ios-how-to-detect-programmatically-when-top-view-controller-is-popped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These four methods can be used in a view controller's appearance callbacks to determine if it is being

**presented**, **dismissed**, or **added** or **removed** as a **child view controller**.

```
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open var isBeingPresented: Bool { get }

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open var isBeingDismissed: Bool { get }


@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open var isMovingToParentViewController: Bool { get }

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open var isMovingFromParentViewController: Bool { get }
```

For example, a view controller can

**check if it is disappearing** because it was **dismissed** or **popped** by asking itself in its **viewWillDisappear**:

method by checking the expression

```
([self isBeingDismissed] || [self isMovingFromParentViewController]).
```

for e.g , you can call the method as

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController())  {
        // we're already on the navigation stack
        // another controller must have been popped off
    }


}
```