# How to Capture a Navigation Back In The ParentController From Specified ChildController

Tags: ios, swift

How to get a specified child_controller in the parent_controller from navigation back comes from?
I only want if the navigation back returns from PERSON_CONTROLLER() and CAR_LIST_CONTROLLER().
If the navigation back from BIKE_LIST_CONTROLLER() or GARAGE_LIST_CONTROLLER() I want to ignore, Picture in below:
[image]

```
class HOME_CONTROLLER: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // what the code to get if navigation back only from PERSON_CONTROLLER() or CAR_LIST_CONTROLLER()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getting the `viewController` from the `transitionCoordinator` you don't have to keep track of it. (Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26308475/2799803)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
    guard let fromViewController = navigationController?.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }
        
    switch fromViewController {
    case is PERSON_CONTROLLER:
        print("We're coming back from PERSON_CONTROLLER")
    case is CAR_LIST_CONTROLLER:
        print("We're coming back from CAR_LIST_CONTROLLER")
    default:
        break // Ignoring
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you save my day. I looking for this since 2 days ago, but I stack and throw to here and got the perfect answer from you, BTW I new comer in swift :-). Once again many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to **keep the track of pushed/active child view controller** from `HOME_CONTROLLER` when any specific view controller is pushed. And when you come back to `HOME_CONTROLLER`, just check the variable `activeChildVC` but the key to this **approach is actively updating the variable** `activeChildVC`'s value **as when any specific child controller is pushed to avoid any conflicts/inconsistencies**. Here's how the required logic to check the back flow from specified view controller looks:

```
import UIKit

enum ChildNavFlows {
  case person
  case bikeList
  case carList
  case garageList
}

class HOME_CONTROLLER: UIViewController {
  
  var activeChildVC: ChildNavFlows?

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    if let childVC = activeChildVC {
      switch childVC {
      case .person:
        print("Came from Person Controller")
      case .carList:
        print("Came from Car List Controller")
      default:
        print("Don't care")
      }
    }
  }
}
```