# How to detect which child view controller was popped up in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have view controller say **A** i am going from **A** to **B**.Then on **B** by pressing back button i am coming to **A**.Now i want to know from which view controller i am coming back.Please tell me how can i do this.I know i can do it by using `viewWillAppear` method but  don't want to use this.

Please tell which is the best way of doing it?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view will appear called");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                  toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    NSLog(@"from VC class %@", [fromVC class]);
    if ([fromVC isKindOfClass:[ControllerYouJustPopped class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Returning from popped controller");

    }

    return nil;
}
```

This really saved me .

Comment: Best answer! An Swift Example would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

You have been push to B-VC from A-VC right.You can come back by popping.

self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)--Write this code in B-VC

VC-ViewController.

Comment: i want to get to know that it was B not C so how can i identify the view controller

Comment: try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949280/which-method-is-called-when-back-button-clicked-in-navigation-controller/7949339#7949339

Answer (score 0):

you can pass id of controller before pop 
 A.h 
 `@property NSInteger childVC;`
 A.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (_childVC == 3){
        //todo
    }
}
```

B.m

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    A *parent = (A *)self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2];
    parent.childVC = 3;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

I do not see other ways

Answer (score -1):

You could use a navigation controller delegate and implement the following UINavigationControllerDelegate method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [navigationController.transitionCoordinator viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    NSLog(@"%@", fromViewController.title);
}
```

Comment: it returns the name of the current view controller.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer with some additional code. The "fromViewController" ist accessible through the navigation controllers transitionCoordinator.

Comment: Did you assign a title to your viewController?

Comment: Yes still return null value